# SOAP URL is not accessible from docker

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

My SOAP URL `http://localhost:9090/soap?wsdl` is reachable from a Spring Boot app.

But when I run a Spring Boot app as a docker container the SOAP URL is not reachable.
At the same time the untertown is reachable http://localhost:8080/actuator

I expose ports 8080 and 9090. Below is the command to run the docker image

```
docker run -p 8080:8080  -p 9090:9090 -t springboot/myspringbootapp
```

I am using a mac and docker for mac.

Answer (score 0):

i found reason in the code i should use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost